# yii2 function callback linkedin return Request failed with code: 404

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, yii2, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a login feature with linkedin on yii2 using `authclient`. But i'm confused, after user login and give access permission with my app, In `successCallback` function i'm trying to debug `$client->getUserAttributes( )` and it just returns error `Exception – yii\authclient\InvalidResponseException Request failed with code: 404`

This is my function successCallback :

```
public $successUrl = '';

public function actions()
  {
    return [
      'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
      ],
      'linkedin' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
          'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
          'successUrl' => $this->successUrl
      ],
    ];
  }

  public function successCallback($client) {
    $data = $client->getUserAttributes();
    print_r(json_encode($data));exit;
  }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Provide more details ... how does the rest look? Did you follow any guides? If so which one and whats different from your coding? Literally your shown code is even less than any of yii2's guides ([yiisoft/yii2-authclient - API Documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/doc/api/2.2/yii-authclient-authaction), [AuthClient Extension for Yii 2](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/doc/guide/2.0/en/quick-start)) ... also: 404 means page not found. Which would imply that some URL is incorrect.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Okay i have edited my question, i've followed guide to add auth action(in my code linkedin)